# How to prevent AKS Ingress from overwriting Application Gateway's existing services?

Tags: azure-aks, azure-application-gateway

I recently had connected an AKS cluster to an Application Gateway and had the services I hosted on the AKS cluster be made accessible through the gateway's public IP. However I realized that whenever I update the Ingress I created the AKS and gateway it overwrites all exisitng settings (pool, backend settings, health probe, etc. I was wondering if there is a way where when we update the Ingress it doesn't overwrite the whole gateway and it simply adds to it?

Also how can I achieve this as well if I were to connect 2 AKS to the one gateway without one of the AKS erasing the entire gateway whenever a new service is created on AKS?

Comment: Can you give us more details about your configuration? Are you using AGIC? if so, how did you install it inside your cluster (eg. via HELM)?

Comment: Yes I used AGIC. So I followed this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/tutorial-ingress-controller-add-on-existing) exactly and ran the aks enable add-on as well as peering the two vnet. After following these instructures I was able to successfully connect the AKS services to the gateway. I recently learned about the AzureIngressProhibitedTarget but had no luck getting it to actually work as it shows me "no match for kind AzureIngressProhibitedTarget in version appgw.ingress.k8s.io/v1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, when installing the AGIC via the AKS add-on, you'll be forced to use the AGIC in the default behaviour, i.e. the AGIC will consider itself as the only one that uses the Application Gateway.
That's why you see that behaviour.

[image]

At the moment, the only way where you can change this AGIC behaviour is by installing it via Helm.
Helm enables you to configure the AGIC as *shared*, and only in this way you can use *AzureIngressProhibitedTarget*.

[image]

eg. AGIC configuration as shared

```
appgw:
subscriptionId: <subscriptionId>    # existing field
resourceGroup: <resourceGroupName>  # existing field
name: <applicationGatewayName>      # existing field
shared: true                        # <<<<< Add this field to enable shared App Gateway >>>>>
```

eg. AzureIngressProhibitedTarget

```
apiVersion: "appgw.ingress.k8s.io/v1"
kind: AzureIngressProhibitedTarget
metadata:
  name: your-custom-prohibitions
spec:
  hostname: your.own-hostname.com
```

For more info:

[Multi-cluster / Shared App Gateway](https://azure.github.io/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/setup/install-existing/#multi-cluster-shared-app-gateway)

[Difference between Helm deployment and AKS Add-On](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/ingress-controller-overview#difference-between-helm-deployment-and-aks-add-on)

Comment: Thank you! I will certainly try it this way. Much appreciated!